# Chromium и Pupeteer не устанавливаются на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, npm, chromium

Пробую установить через файл зависимостей Cromium и Puppeteer.

```
npm install
```

и

```
npm install --save puppeteer
```

Получаю
[image: консоль]

Пробовал сделать

```
sudo chmod 777 -R ./node_modules
```

Обновлял и переустанавливал, проверял версии и количество версий установленных компонентов. Ошибка та же. 
Версия Node 8.11.0, npm 5.6.0. Директория node_modules с замком.
Как установить компоненты не удаляя папку?